# Inside Update Panel, images are not working during partial postbacks

Tags: asp.net, ajax, partial-postback

I have an update panel like below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel_SomeDate" UpdateMode="Conditional"  runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="IsMail" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table runat="server" id="MailDateTable">
            <tr id="MailDateTableRow" runat="server">
                <td nowrap="true" valign="top"  width="180px" class="ms-formlabel">
                    <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
                        <nobr>Mailing Date<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span></nobr>
                    </h3>
                </td>
                <td valign="top"  width="480px" class="ms-formbody">
                    <span dir="none">
                        <TestDate:DatePicker runat="server" ID="MailingDate" AllowEmpty="false" CalloutEnabled="true" ValidationEnabled="true" />
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

During partial post backs i need set `MailingDate.visible = false` or true (based on IsMail value). `MailingDate` is user control Id.

Here i have a calender image inside `TestDate:DatePicker` user control. by clicking on this i am selecting date value to the text box.

Now problem is if i make `visible = true` or false during partial post backs, this image is not coming. i am unable to see the image. please help.

I have some code inside datepicker user control `Page_Load` like below, will it causing any issue?.

```
if (this.Enabled)
{
    string script = "$(function(){$(\".datepicker\").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImage: '/images/calendar.gif', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonText: 'Select a date', onSelect:" + ( OnSelect ?? "function(){}" ) + " });});";
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "DatePickerScriptKey", script, true);
    this.Page.RegisterStyleBlock( "DatePickCss", ".ui-datepicker{ display: none; }" );
}
```

Comment: Some times The post back does not work. Then you have to rewrite again all the update panel. Then It works. Try It. I faced this problem sometimes. `Note:` You Shouldnot Copy and paste the updatepanel or its content.